# Can the embedded jetty server work on ios devices?

Tags: android, iphone, servlets, webserver, embedded-jetty

Can the embedded jetty server work on ios devices ?..I have a requirement to build an offline web application that should work on all devices (iphon, android phones, mac, linux etc )?

Comment: I want to use this as well, you have some answers already?

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research around it ,and couldn't find ways to get the embedded jetty server to work on ios devices. So the answer so far is no.